# I want to change date format of form control class type is date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Format is following this gives me mm/dd/yyyy i want to change into yyyy/mm/dd format

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>dev End Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="dev_end_date">
</div>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149869/7040146) and other answers on this question.

Comment: Its impossible to change format. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

you can add '`data-date-format`' like

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD"/>
```

check this [link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a simple (and working) solution like date-util for polymer that allows you to use a tag like this one:

```
<date-util format="dd/MM/yyyy"></date-util>
```

and adapt it as an input field... or you can get creative and pop-up complete date-pickers